# Running the Data Loader from the command line

Tags: data-loader, cli, commandline

I'm trying to setup a scheduled export with the data loader.  I'm trying to follow the instructions provided by Salesforce [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_create_encryption_key.htm#:%7E:text=In%20this%20example%2C%20the%20path,key.) but can't get past Step 1.

Has anyone had a similar issue trying to create an encryption key file?  Everytime I run `C:\Users\mgodfroy.CLG\dataloader\v53.0.2\bin>encrypt.bat -k` I get the following result:

> Files\Zulu\zulu-18] was unexpected at this time.

Not sure how to get around this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any chance to install zulu not in Program Files folder but in path without spaces?

Comment: @kurunve thanks.  What do you mean path without spaces?  Should I try to install in C:\Users\mgodfroy.CLG\dataloader ?

Comment: I have faced many issues earlier while using zulu-18, could you try using zulu-11 instead ? It has worked for me in the past

Comment: @MattcG91 that would be my idea -- I had similar issues before, and this approach helped

Comment: @prabuddhkumar I installed Java11 in the same folder as the dataloader and I'm getting a new error this time: "\Sennheiser\SenncomSDK\ was unexpected at this time." It looks to me like Sennheiser has to do with Cisco/Jabber.  Not sure how I'll get around this!

Comment: @kurunve no luck with that, but thank you.  It's now saying \Sennheiser\SenncomSDK was unexpected at this time.  I think I am going to have to get in touch with my IT department